# Beginner's Q on Compiler Errors

Tags: c++

I am very new to programming and coding so I am facing problems some of which I can't seem to understand. I've really looked for answers but in vain.

The compiler mentioned 2 errors:

> In function 'intmain()':

and

> expected ';'before '{' token

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
main ()
{
     float a, b, c, D, x1, x2, x;
     cout<<"enter the value of a :";
     cin>>a;
     cout<<"enter the value of b :";
     cin>>b;
     cout<<"enter the value of c :";
     cin>>c;
     D= b*b-4*a*c;
     if(D>0)
     {
     x1= (-b-sqrt(D))/(2*a);
     x2= (-b+sqrt(D))/(2*a);
     cout<<"the roots of the equation are"<<x1<<"and"<<x2<<" \n";
     }
     else if (D=0)
     {x= -b/(2*a);
     cout<<"the double root of the equation is"<<x<<" \n";
     }
     else (D<0)
     {
     cout<<"no solution \n:";
     }
     system("pause") ;
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

I am answering this question because it could be a canonical case of completely broken code. Here are the errors:

`using namespace std;` <-- one should never do this.

`main ()` <-- a prototype for `main` is `int main()` or `int main(int, char* [])`

`float a, b, c, D, x1, x2, x;` <-- do not get in habit of declaring all variables 'in advance'. Instead, declare them as you need them.

`else if (D=0)` <--- this is not what you wanted to do. You assigned 0 do D. You wanted to compare them, so use `if (D == 0)`

`else (D<0)` <-- missing `if`. Should be `else if (D < 0)`

`{x= -b/(2*a);` <-- this is just a terrible style. Do not put other statements after opening brace unless the body is a single line, and in this case close the brace in the very same line.

And everywhere - format your code properly, like a text.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will fix the problem by using the solutions you provided me with.

Answer (score 0):

It's here:

```
else (D<0)
```

The compiler is upset because it wanted a body for the `else`, and you didn't provide one.

The syntax is

```
if (condition)
{

}
else
{

}
```

You don't need to tell the compiler what the "else" condition is; it's when `condition` is false.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take your points into consideration and try to improve my work.